# AWS CodeDeploy is not supporting ruby v3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am using Ruby 3.0.1 and Rails 6.1 for one of my applications. I want to use AWS CodeDeploy to deploy my application on the server. When I tried to install CodeDeploy on my server, I was getting the following error:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby

    aws_codedeploy_agent was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      Ruby (~> 2.0)

Ruby (~> 2.0), which is required by gem 'aws_codedeploy_agent', is not
available in the local ruby installation
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]
```

It seems like AWS CodeDeploy still not supporting ruby 3+. I have created a new issue on the CodeDeploy GitHub repo: https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/301.

Does anyone know how to use CodeDeploy with the latest version of Ruby? or, What are the alternatives of CodeDeploy?

Thanks.

Comment: The version of that particular gem on ruby-gems.org was released in 2016. Even the HEAD version on GitHub only requires Ruby 2.3, which was end of life two years ago. It appears to be dead.

Comment: @rmlockerd Where are you reading "requires ruby 2.3"? Just because [this file says 2.3.8](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/master/.ruby-version), that doesn't mean the project is dependant on 2.3. In the gemspec, [it requires `~> 2.0`](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/3c39d545b108c29ae46dfe17aa98e518f88f1a14/codedeploy_agent.gemspec#L12). Additionally [here, it explicitly requires ruby 2.0 --> 2.7](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/a724d586f0934a0e3d78f40c7bb83ec285730633/bin/install#L215-L217).

Comment: Regarding the question of "does it work on v3?", I don't know... Why don't you try it, and see? You could fork the project and relax the ruby constraints listed above to see if it runs without error.

Comment: Also I disagree with the comment: "It appears to be dead"; the project was last updated 2 weeks ago!! I'm just guessing nobody has particularly pushed for ruby v3 compatibility yet.

Comment: I saw someone fiddled with it recently but there’s one published version from 5 years ago, and the documentation and test coverage is sparse compared to other projects under aws. Maybe dead is the wrong word, but it doesn’t appear to be thriving.